# Why a reading in numpy array would be slower than in a dict?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I tried to make a comparaison between reading in a dictionary and in a numpy array.

I was sure that the numpy array will be faster, as when I do `numpy_array[i]` it just have to check the ith word after the start of the array, but doing `dictionary[i]` will use hash computation and use a more complex data structure.

However, I tried it whith %timeit in ipython, with the dictionary and the array being the same, and those are my results :

```
In [161]: def getter(obj, n): return obj[n]

In [162]: %timeit getter(dictionary, 6)
The slowest run took 10.84 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
10000000 loops, best of 3: 110 ns per loop

In [163]: %timeit getter(numpyarray, 6)
The slowest run took 27.87 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000000 loops, best of 3: 180 ns per loop
```

How can you explain that ?

Comment: More often we compare arrays with lists.  `numpy's` speed comes in whole array operations the work in compiled code.  Python level iteration and item indexing is slower.

Comment: Well, these results are a little to very less significance as there is much more overhead involved in reaching and reading memory than to compute complex hash functions. A vague explanation can be that numpy has significant overheads calling its c implementation rather than python's standard lib.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to note is that a numpy array has quite a lot of book-keeping, see [ndarray attributes](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/arrays.ndarray.html#array-attributes). You can corrupt an array, just for fun, by changing the value of the `strides` attribute.

Also, if you take an element out a float array, you don't get a native Python float, but rather an `np.float64` object.

```
>>> type(np.linspace(0, 1)[0])
numpy.float64
```

I suspect that creating a np.float64 object has more overhead than a native Python float; at least, it has many more attributes and methods. Not sure, though; it's not a normal object that you can add attributes to.

By the way, accessing element 6 of a list is about as fast as on a `dict`.